# MDX calculated non-measured member

Tags: ssas, mdx, member

I am trying to set a calculated member to create alternate roll up for out legal entities.
Company `XYZ as Co X + Co Y  + Co Y.`

I would to have all measures (expense, revenue etc) calculate for this new roll up.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Take a look at the following example, I am trying to add a calculated member to the Product.Category dimension attribute. This new member is called "Bikes&Accessories" and it results the data for any measure for "Bikes" & "Accessories" categories.

The first query shows the initial data
    select 
    {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
    [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity],
    [Measures].[Internet Tax Amount],
    [Measures].[Internet Gross Profit Margin]
    }on 0 , 
    [Product].[Category].allmembers
    on 1
    from
    [Adventure Works]

Result

[image]

Now lets add the new calculated member. Observe that I have used different measures, each one is aggregated based on its type.

with member [Product].[Category].[Bikes&Accessories]
as 
aggregate({[Product].[Category].&[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itNjI.png),[Product].[Category].&[4]},[Measures].[Measures].currentmember)

```
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity],
[Measures].[Internet Tax Amount],
[Measures].[Internet Gross Profit Margin]
}on 0 , 
[Product].[Category].allmembers
on 1
from
[Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

Comment: @tolya if the answer was helpful you might consider marking it as answer.